# Power Consumption and Bit density in DRAM and SRAM

Tags: memory, ram

I have read lot of answers on internet for this question but answers are ambiguous and I'm not able to understand the correct ans to this question. Someone please explain the reasoning behind your answer as well.

In comparison with static RAM memory, the dynamic RAM memory has

1. Lower bit density and higher power consumption
2. Higher bit density and lower power consumption
3. Lower bit density and lower power consumption
4. None of the option

My reasoning is, Static RAM has lower density because there are total 6 Transistors(Occupying More Space) while DRAM has one transistor and capacitor.

So, Density (SRAM) < Density of (DRAM).

Power Consumption:

As DRAM has a capacitor it, continuously leaks current. Therefore it requires frequent refresh which consumes power.

So, Power Consumption(DRAM)> Power Consumption(SRAM)

Please correct me if I'm wrong.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

DRAM needs continuous refreshment as it uses capacitor that leaks current. To overcome this, SRAM was introduced. It does not leak current but consume more power, why?

Because of its architecture. You know Both D & SRAM use transistors to store data which are made up of semiconductor materials. Usually it is a n-p-n transistor that stores bits or charges.

Both the memory use same transistor which can hold same amount of data each. But SRAM is designed with 6 transistors so that each transistor can hold less data and work faster.

That is why DRAM is more densed than SRAM.

Also a n-p-n transistor is activated by applying very small amount of current. Now, same amount of charges or bits can be stored in DRAM using a single transistor, while SRAM needs six. So, SRAM needs more power to activate per bit. And for same amount of data SRAM consume more power.

In conclusion we can say,
**SRAM has lower bit density and higher power consumption.
DRAM has higher bit density and lower power consumption.**

I am not an expert but thats what I understand. If incorrect, please make me correct.